# Gradle project sync failed in Android Studio, Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: android-studio

The error appears immediately when creating the project in Android Studio
Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly.

Build:
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\User.android\manual-offline-m2

I installed a new Gradle, but it didn't help, turned off offline mode, didn't help either, and I really don't have the "manual-offline-m2" file. I haven't found where I can download it

Comment: I just needed to create an empty folder named "manual-offline-m2"
*Facepalm*